Optimal knot placement for approximating this function with B-spline.
I have the following data points, which all lie along a smooth, unknown, function (it looks sigmoidal but might not be):

I want to approximate it rather accurately with B-splines, either quadratic or cubic.
All y-axis points lie in the range [0,1], and it would be problematic if the spline osciallated above or below this.
I can use any knots and as much or as little of this data to guide instruct the approximation but I would like to minimise it as much as possible for purposes of performance in repeated calculations.
Question

What is the best advice for the choice of either cubic or quadratic spline?
What is the likely best position of the knot points and what is smallest number workable?
Should all the data be used as a least squares solution or will taking a subset make any difference?

For anyone interested in the data:
1.2571854808889482 1e-05
1.1715936957715238 0.0020099599999998663
1.1581100337458663 0.004009919999999889
1.1497738225352752 0.006009879999999912
1.1436227230256621 0.008009839999999935
1.1386992137659406 0.010009799999999958
1.1345676821128718 0.01200975999999987
1.1309918619925765 0.014009719999999892
1.1278287444616926 0.016009679999999915
1.1249849624664643 0.018009639999999938
1.1223960756796347 0.02000959999999996
1.1200156718171634 0.022009559999999873
1.1178091749060786 0.024009519999999895
1.115750110225028 0.026009479999999918
1.1138177398409588 0.02800943999999994
1.1119955051865678 0.030009399999999964
1.1102699665194977 0.032009359999999876
1.1086300600076828 0.0340093199999999
1.1070665644695008 0.03600927999999992
1.1055717103897877 0.038009239999999944
1.10413888785308 0.04000919999999997
1.102762424732066 0.04200915999999988
1.101437415728793 0.0440091199999999
1.1001595888536264 0.046009079999999924
1.0989251998892486 0.04800903999999995
1.097730948064225 0.05000899999999986
1.0965739080038686 0.05200895999999988
1.0954514743169563 0.054008919999999905
1.0943613160949746 0.05600887999999993
1.093301339262963 0.05800883999999995
1.0922696552052207 0.06000879999999986
1.0912645544473503 0.062008759999999885
1.0902844844441077 0.06400871999999991
1.0893280307251196 0.06600867999999993
1.088393900805143 0.06800863999999995
1.087480910384636 0.07000859999999987
1.086587971458882 0.07200855999999989
1.0857140820263242 0.07400851999999991
1.084858317143848 0.07600847999999993
1.0840198211220986 0.07800843999999996
1.0831978006901732 0.08000839999999987
1.0823915189881614 0.08200835999999989
1.0816002902696207 0.08400831999999991
1.080823475215246 0.08600827999999994
1.080060476774699 0.08800823999999996
1.0793107364664676 0.09000819999999987
1.0785737310762706 0.0920081599999999
1.077848969703388 0.09400811999999992
1.0771359911116392 0.09600807999999994
1.0764343613479204 0.09800803999999996
1.0757436715963768 0.10000799999999987
1.0750635362406604 0.1020079599999999
1.0743935911104192 0.10400791999999992
1.0737334918913028 0.10600787999999994
1.0730829126804433 0.10800783999999997
1.0724415446716578 0.11000779999999988
1.0718090949565804 0.1120077599999999
1.0711852854296182 0.11400771999999992
1.0705698517860731 0.11600767999999995
1.0699625426040402 0.11800763999999997
1.069363118501775 0.12000759999999988
1.0687713513631694 0.1220075599999999
1.068187023624812 0.12400751999999993
1.0676099276188138 0.12600747999999995
1.0670398649662278 0.12800743999999997
1.0664766460164357 0.13000739999999988
1.0659200893283627 0.1320073599999999
1.065370021189816 0.13400731999999993
1.0648262751716149 0.13600727999999995
1.0642886917135215 0.13800723999999998
1.0637571177392742 0.1400071999999999
1.0632314062982922 0.1420071599999999
1.0627114162318516 0.14400711999999993
1.0621970118617485 0.14600707999999996
1.0616880626996403 0.14800703999999998
1.0611844431754371 0.1500069999999999
1.0606860323832519 0.1520069599999999
1.0601927138435598 0.15400691999999994
1.0597043752803357 0.15600687999999996
1.0592209084120436 0.15800683999999998
1.0587422087554554 0.1600067999999999
1.058268175441357 0.16200675999999992
1.0577987110412859 0.16400671999999994
1.0573337214045126 0.16600667999999996
1.056873115504542 0.16800663999999987
1.0564168052944736 0.1700065999999999
1.0559647055706083 0.17200655999999992
1.0555167338437452 0.17400651999999994
1.0550728102176445 0.17600647999999997
1.0546328572741872 0.17800643999999988
1.054196799964784 0.1800063999999999
1.053764565507635 0.18200635999999992
1.0533360832904568 0.18400631999999995
1.0529112847783324 0.18600627999999997
1.0524901034263636 0.18800623999999988
1.0520724745968228 0.1900061999999999
1.0516583354805298 0.19200615999999993
1.0512476250221947 0.19400611999999995
1.050840283849489 0.19600607999999997
1.050436254205621 0.19800603999999988
1.050035479885208 0.2000059999999999
1.0496379061732553 0.20200595999999993
1.0492434797870573 0.20400591999999995
1.048852148820858 0.20600587999999997
1.0484638626931093 0.2080058399999999
1.048078572096185 0.2100057999999999
1.0476962289484115 0.21200575999999993
1.0473167863482875 0.21400571999999995
1.0469401985307722 0.21600567999999998
1.0465664208255332 0.2180056399999999
1.046195409617044 0.2200055999999999
1.045827122306436 0.22200555999999994
1.0454615172750124 0.22400551999999996
1.0450985538493347 0.22600547999999998
1.0447381922678032 0.2280054399999999
1.0443803936486529 0.23000539999999992
1.0440251199592936 0.23200535999999994
1.0436723339869256 0.23400531999999996
1.0433219993103675 0.23600527999999998
1.042974080273037 0.2380052399999999
1.0426285419570254 0.24000519999999992
1.0422853501582154 0.24200515999999994
1.0419444713623895 0.24400511999999996
1.0416058727222817 0.24600508
1.0412695220355288 0.2480050399999999
1.040935387723478 0.2500049999999999
1.0406034388108087 0.25200495999999994
1.0402736449059367 0.25400491999999997
1.0399459761821552 0.25600488
1.0396204033594878 0.2580048399999999
1.0392968976872166 0.2600047999999999
1.0389754309270545 0.26200475999999995
1.0386559753369358 0.26400471999999997
1.0383385036553954 0.26600468
1.0380229890865098 0.2680046399999999
1.0377094052853784 0.27000459999999993
1.0373977263441185 0.27200455999999995
1.0370879267783537 0.27400452
1.0367799815141738 0.27600448
1.0364738658755457 0.2780044399999999
1.0361695555721573 0.28000439999999993
1.0358670266876748 0.28200435999999995
1.0355662556683984 0.28400432
1.035267219312297 0.28600428
1.0349698947584067 0.2880042399999999
1.0346742594765832 0.29000419999999993
1.034380291257585 0.29200415999999996
1.0340879682034816 0.29400412
1.0337972687183694 0.29600408
1.033508171499385 0.2980040399999999
1.0332206555280035 0.30000399999999994
1.0329347000616098 0.30200395999999996
1.032650284625334 0.30400392
1.0323673890041378 0.3060038799999999
1.0320859932351458 0.3080038399999999
1.031806077600209 0.31000379999999994
1.0315276226186931 0.31200375999999996
1.0312506090404836 0.31400372
1.0309750178391974 0.3160036799999999
1.0307008302055958 0.3180036399999999
1.0304280275411888 0.32000359999999994
1.0301565914520254 0.32200355999999997
1.0298865037426626 0.32400352
1.0296177464103047 0.3260034799999999
1.0293503016391097 0.3280034399999999
1.0290841517946545 0.33000339999999995
1.0288192794185533 0.33200335999999997
1.0285556672232252 0.33400332
1.0282932980868025 0.3360032799999999
1.0280321550481788 0.3380032399999999
1.0277722213021878 0.34000319999999995
1.0275134801949106 0.34200316
1.0272559152191074 0.34400312
1.0269995100097662 0.3460030799999999
1.0267442483397666 0.34800303999999993
1.0264901141156566 0.35000299999999995
1.0262370913735324 0.35200296
1.025985164275024 0.35400292
1.0257343171033793 0.3560028799999999
1.025484534259644 0.35800283999999993
1.0252358002589346 0.36000279999999996
1.0249880997268002 0.36200276
1.024741417395671 0.36400272
1.0244957381013897 0.3660026799999999
1.0242510467798238 0.36800263999999994
1.0240073284635554 0.37000259999999996
1.0237645682786454 0.37200256
1.0235227514414709 0.37400252
1.0232818632556322 0.3760024799999999
1.0230418891089264 0.37800243999999994
1.0228028144703878 0.38000239999999996
1.0225646248873892 0.38200236
1.0223273059828057 0.38400232
1.0220908434522362 0.3860022799999999
1.021855223061281 0.38800223999999994
1.021620430642875 0.39000219999999997
1.0213864520946736 0.39200216
1.021153273376487 0.39400212
1.0209208805077683 0.3960020799999999
1.0206892595651436 0.39800203999999995
1.020458396679992 0.40000199999999997
1.020228278036067 0.40200196
1.0199988898671613 0.40400192
1.0197702184548123 0.4060018799999999
1.0195422501260474 0.40800183999999995
1.0193149712511669 0.41000179999999997
1.0190883682415637 0.41200176
1.0188624275475775 0.41400172
1.018637135656384 0.41600167999999993
1.0184124790899154 0.41800163999999995
1.018188444402814 0.4200016
1.0179650181804143 0.42200156
1.0177421870367542 0.4240015199999999
1.0175199376126147 0.42600147999999993
1.0172982565735862 0.42800143999999996
1.0170771306081594 0.4300014
1.0168565464258417 0.43200136
1.016636490755296 0.4340013199999999
1.0164169503425031 0.43600127999999994
1.0161979119489437 0.43800123999999996
1.0159793623498032 0.4400012
1.0157612883321934 0.44200116
1.0155436766933943 0.4440011199999999
1.0153265142391128 0.44600107999999994
1.015109787781758 0.44800103999999996
1.0148934841387334 0.450001
1.0146775901307412 0.45200096
1.0144620925801042 0.4540009199999999
1.0142469783090982 0.45600087999999994
1.0140322341382975 0.45800083999999996
1.0138178468849324 0.4600008
1.013603803361257 0.46200076
1.0133900903729274 0.4640007199999999
1.0131766947173868 0.46600067999999994
1.0129636031822637 0.46800063999999997
1.012750802543772 0.4700006
1.0125382795651223 0.47200056
1.0123260209949374 0.4740005199999999
1.012114013565673 0.47600047999999995
1.011902243992044 0.47800043999999997
1.0116906989694536 0.4800004
1.0114793651724265 0.48200036
1.0112682292530442 0.48400031999999993
1.011057277839381 0.48600027999999995
1.0108464975339433 0.48800024
1.010635874912107 0.4900002
1.0104253965205552 0.49200016
1.0102150488757151 0.49400011999999993
1.010004818462193 0.49600007999999995
1.0097946917312068 0.49800004
1.0095846550990137 0.5
1.0093746945754525 0.50199996
1.0091647946858688 0.50399992
1.0089549396370316 0.50599988
1.0087451136933296 0.50799984
1.0085353011747769 0.5099998
1.0083254864550282 0.5119997599999999
1.0081156539593958 0.5139997199999999
1.0079057881628748 0.51599968
1.0076958735881705 0.51799964
1.0074858948037293 0.5199996
1.0072758364217727 0.52199956
1.0070656830963332 0.52399952
1.0068554195212902 0.52599948
1.0066450304284078 0.52799944
1.0064345005853703 0.5299993999999999
1.0062238147938167 0.5319993599999999
1.0060129578873749 0.5339993199999999
1.005801914729691 0.53599928
1.005590670212455 0.53799924
1.005379209253424 0.5399992
1.0051675167944365 0.54199916
1.0049555777994257 0.5439991200000001
1.0047433772524204 0.54599908
1.004530900155542 0.54799904
1.0043181315269911 0.5499989999999999
1.0041050563990255 0.5519989599999999
1.0038916598159267 0.55399892
1.0036779268319573 0.55599888
1.003463842509304 0.55799884
1.0032493919160084 0.5599988
1.0030345601238848 0.56199876
1.0028193322064223 0.5639987200000001
1.0026036932366706 0.56599868
1.0023876282851107 0.56799864
1.002171122417506 0.5699985999999999
1.0019541606927358 0.5719985599999999
1.0017367281606089 0.57399852
1.0015188098596555 0.57599848
1.0013003908148987 0.57799844
1.0010814560356018 0.5799984
1.0008619905129919 0.58199836
1.0006419792179586 0.58399832
1.0004214070987254 0.58599828
1.0002002590784944 0.58799824
0.999978520053062 0.5899981999999999
0.9997561748884038 0.5919981599999999
0.9995332084182292 0.59399812
0.9993096054415023 0.59599808
0.9990853507199291 0.59799804
0.9988604289754098 0.599998
0.9986348248874531 0.60199796
0.9984085230905531 0.60399792
0.998181508171525 0.60599788
0.9979537646668014 0.60799784
0.9977252770596836 0.6099977999999999
0.9974960297775486 0.61199776
0.9972660071890104 0.61399772
0.9970351936010322 0.61599768
0.9968035732559891 0.61799764
0.9965711303286786 0.6199976
0.9963378489232773 0.6219975600000001
0.9961037130702415 0.62399752
0.9958687067231508 0.62599748
0.9956328137554902 0.62799744
0.9953960179573712 0.6299973999999999
0.9951583030321877 0.63199736
0.9949196525932049 0.63399732
0.9946800501600799 0.63599728
0.9944394791553083 0.63799724
0.9941979229005987 0.6399972
0.9939553646131688 0.6419971600000001
0.993711787401961 0.64399712
0.9934671742637763 0.64599708
0.9932215080793214 0.64799704
0.9929747716091671 0.6499969999999999
0.9927269474896143 0.65199696
0.9924780182284644 0.65399692
0.9922279662006903 0.65599688
0.9919767736440052 0.65799684
0.9917244226543238 0.6599968
0.9914708951811148 0.6619967600000001
0.9912161730226365 0.66399672
0.9909602378210562 0.66599668
0.9907030710574443 0.6679966399999999
0.9904446540466418 0.6699965999999999
0.9901849679319957 0.67199656
0.9899239936799556 0.67399652
0.9896617120745295 0.67599648
0.9893981037115896 0.67799644
0.9891331489930273 0.6799964000000001
0.9888668281207459 0.6819963600000001
0.9885991210904901 0.68399632
0.9883300076855029 0.68599628
0.9880594674700048 0.6879962399999999
0.9877874797824864 0.6899962
0.9875140237288101 0.69199616
0.9872390781751121 0.69399612
0.9869626217404949 0.69599608
0.9866846327895059 0.69799604
0.9864050894243905 0.6999960000000001
0.9861239694771126 0.7019959600000001
0.9858412505011315 0.70399592
0.9855569097629274 0.70599588
0.9852709242332639 0.7079958399999999
0.9849832705781769 0.7099958
0.9846939251496797 0.71199576
0.9844028639761713 0.71399572
0.9841100627525364 0.71599568
0.9838154968299248 0.71799564
0.9835191412051948 0.7199956000000001
0.9832209705100087 0.72199556
0.9829209589995643 0.72399552
0.9826190805409473 0.72599548
0.9823153086010873 0.7279954399999999
0.982009616234302 0.7299954
0.9817019760694112 0.73199536
0.9813923602963988 0.73399532
0.9810807406526079 0.73599528
0.9807670884084437 0.73799524
0.9804513743525651 0.7399952000000001
0.9801335687765396 0.74199516
0.9798136414589385 0.74399512
0.9794915616488467 0.74599508
0.9791672980487596 0.7479950399999999
0.978840818796838 0.749995
0.9785120914484924 0.75199496
0.9781810829572634 0.75399492
0.9778477596549655 0.75599488
0.977512087231059 0.7579948400000001
0.9771740307112116 0.7599948000000001
0.9768335544350117 0.76199476
0.9764906220327901 0.76399472
0.9761451964015067 0.76599468
0.9757972396796547 0.76799464
0.9754467132211342 0.7699946
0.9750935775680404 0.77199456
0.9747377924223123 0.77399452
0.9743793166161828 0.77599448
0.9740181080813665 0.7779944400000001
0.9736541238169193 0.7799944
0.9732873198556994 0.78199436
0.9729176512293537 0.78399432
0.9725450719317502 0.78599428
0.972169534880772 0.78799424
0.9717909918783794 0.7899942
0.9714093935688494 0.79199416
0.9710246893950825 0.79399412
0.9706368275528737 0.79599408
0.9702457549430261 0.7979940400000001
0.9698514171211846 0.799994
0.9694537582452551 0.80199396
0.9690527210202667 0.80399392
0.9686482466405243 0.80599388
0.9682402747288869 0.80799384
0.9678287432729976 0.8099938
0.9674135885582773 0.81199376
0.9669947450974782 0.81399372
0.9665721455565836 0.81599368
0.9661457206768188 0.8179936400000001
0.9657153991925244 0.8199936
0.9652811077446201 0.82199356
0.9648427707893722 0.82399352
0.964400310502149 0.8259934800000001
0.9639536466758273 0.82799344
0.9635026966134852 0.8299934
0.9630473750149887 0.83199336
0.9625875938570424 0.83399332
0.9621232622662454 0.8359932800000001
0.9616542863846514 0.8379932400000001
0.9611805692272886 0.8399932
0.960702010531051 0.84199316
0.9602185065943211 0.84399312
0.9597299501066237 0.8459930800000001
0.9592362299675533 0.84799304
0.9587372310941458 0.849993
0.9582328342157888 0.85199296
0.9577229156556831 0.85399292
0.9572073470977727 0.8559928800000001
0.9566859953379551 0.8579928400000001
0.9561587220182765 0.8599928
0.9556253833426773 0.86199276
0.95508582977272 0.86399272
0.9545399057015677 0.86599268
0.9539874491043032 0.86799264
0.9534282911624833 0.8699926
0.9528622558605927 0.87199256
0.9522891595518167 0.87399252
0.9517088104902663 0.8759924800000001
0.9511210083264695 0.87799244
0.9505255435625837 0.8799924
0.9499221969633769 0.88199236
0.9493107389185597 0.88399232
0.948690928751528 0.8859922800000001
0.9480625139689749 0.88799224
0.9474252294451464 0.8899922
0.9467787965337366 0.89199216
0.9461229220995183 0.8939921200000001
0.9454572974607728 0.8959920800000001
0.9447815972323989 0.89799204
0.9440954780582037 0.899992
0.9433985772192902 0.90199196
0.9426905111036032 0.9039919200000001
0.9419708735195481 0.90599188
0.9412392338340714 0.90799184
0.9404951349126432 0.9099918
0.9397380908351072 0.91199176
0.9389675843572576 0.9139917200000001
0.9381830640831489 0.9159916800000001
0.9373839413073553 0.91799164
0.9365695864795015 0.9199916
0.9357393252351054 0.92199156
0.934892433926808 0.9239915200000001
0.9340281345780159 0.92599148
0.933145589166323 0.92799144
0.9322438931261906 0.9299914
0.9313220679383868 0.93199136
0.9303790526465561 0.9339913200000001
0.9294136941075974 0.9359912800000001
0.9284247357404205 0.93799124
0.9274108044846859 0.9399912
0.9263703956140523 0.94199116
0.9253018549628512 0.9439911200000001
0.9242033580150292 0.94599108
0.9230728851614256 0.94799104
0.921908192244644 0.949991
0.9207067752639566 0.95199096
0.9194658277832195 0.9539909200000001
0.9181821891400672 0.9559908800000001
0.916852280947145 0.95799084
0.9154720285353298 0.9599908
0.9140367628086193 0.9619907600000001
0.912541096297715 0.9639907200000001
0.9109787647594229 0.96599068
0.90934242206429 0.96799064
0.9076233706778903 0.9699906
0.90581120164919 0.9719905600000001
0.9038933047271761 0.9739905200000001
0.9018541875491962 0.97599048
0.899674506295678 0.97799044
0.8973296461817423 0.9799904
0.8947875728987599 0.9819903600000001
0.8920054497951577 0.9839903200000001
0.888924050370546 0.98599028
0.8854579627803952 0.98799024
0.8814770563771254 0.9899902
0.8767676659292093 0.9919901600000001
0.8709387737577621 0.9939901200000001
0.8631390576229525 0.99599008
0.8507713776244531 0.99799004
0.7791141768944588 0.99999


Do you want to exactly interpolate the first and last points? Do you know anything about the starting and ending derivatives (should they be zero, for example)?

The data looks very smooth and very dense. I’d guess that least-squares approximation by a polynomial of degree 6 or 7 would work fine. Depends what you mean by “rather accurately”.

I think the derivatives tend to zero, but that they might not be exactly zero in the range shown on the chart
